# Xlib: Shutdown X server cleanly

Tags: c, xlib

I'm playing around with Xlib. Want to write a simple window manager for the purpose of education.

Is there a function in the Xlib library to close all windows and shutdown the X Server?

I found the `XDestroySubwindows()` function. But is there another function to close X cleanly?

Comment: Did you take a look how [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/) does it? The source code is very approachable.

Comment: Yes. But **dwm** doesn't shutdown X. At least I didn't find any hints in the code yet. There is a static function `quit()` to exit the main loop, but will not be called. **LightDM** as example sends a `SIGTERM` to the server.

Comment: Usually when you launch X it launches another program. When that program terminates, X shuts down. Unless you mean to implement a function which actively shuts down X, in which case `SIGTERM` is the way to go.